# Get the name of the textbox in Partial

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

```
@model DateTime?

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var NameField = $(".pdate");
alert(NameField.attr("name"));
var objCal1 = new AMIB.persianCalendar(NameField);
});
</script>

@Html.TextBox("", Model, new { @class = "pdate" })

@Html.Hidden("", Model)
```

[image]

no display messagebox!!!!
and set under line
no display messagebox!!!!
and set under line
no display messagebox!!!!
and set under line

Answer (score 0):

Your text box has no name. Give name like following

```
@Html.TextBox("aName", Model, new { @class = "pdate" })
```